# How can I get the information from "coordinates" and save it in a PHP variable?

Tags: php, coordinates, mapbox, geojson

I'm looking for some ways but I'm having a lot of difficulty ... I just need the information that is in "coordinates" and put it in a PHP

```
<script>
        mapboxgl.accessToken = 'MY_KEY :3';
    
        var client = new MapboxClient(mapboxgl.accessToken);
    
        var address = 'white house';
        var test = client.geocodeForward(address, function(err, data, res) {
    
    
          var coordinates = data.features[0].center;
 
          document.write(coordinates);
          //console.log(coordinates);
     
          var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
            container: 'map',
            style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v10',
            center: coordinates,
            zoom: 14
          });
          new mapboxgl.Marker()
            .setLngLat(coordinates)
            .addTo(map);
        });
    
      </script>
    </head>  
    <body>
      <div id='map'></div>
    </body>
```

A very simple example is this

```
<?php $coord = 'coordinates'; ?>
```

Comment: To transfer values between Javascript and PHP, you'd need to make an AJAX call.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what you want to calculate but there are all kinds of  API's that you can use with php.

e.g. convert an address to the coordinates..

MAPBOX API for Geocoding:
https://docs.mapbox.com/help/how-mapbox-works/geocoding/

Google Maps is an alternative solution:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/overview

Comment: I have the 'address' variable that receives an address ... with this variable the code searches for the location (lat, lng) and saves it in the 'coordinates' variable ... I would like a PHP variable to receive the value that contains the variable 'coordinates'. Example: $ varphp = varcorrdinates;

Comment: No. The code displays a map. including this address - this is a big difference. 

Do you need to display the map OR NOT?  or is it enough to claculate the coordinates?    I am not sure if you understand the problem.   FIRST the PHP code is run and sent to the browser.  MUCH LATER the JS is run in the browser long after the pfp code is run. To  get the JS variable back into the PHP world you would have to POST/GET/ AJAX the var nack into a php script.